# I'm try do a loop in my list ID and get them form my mongoose database

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm try do a loop in my list ID and get them form my mongoose database 
so this is a simple example to the problem that i have here

```
function myFunction(mongooseModel, idList) { 
const myList = []
idList.forEach(ID => {
    mongooseModel.findById(ID).then(result => { myList.push(result) })
});
return(myList)
```

}

the problem is that the return part are run before all findById part is done because findById is a async function so my code aren't run in order.  it get return before all the promises done

this is what I'm real trying to do

```
router.get('/customers', authentication.checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
bookDB.findById(req.user.book, (err, result) => {
    const list = []
    result.customers.forEach(ID => {
        customerDB.findById(ID).then(customer => { list.push(customer) })
    });
    res.send(list)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your actual question you can make use of `Promise.all()`:

```
router.get('/customers', authentication.checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    bookDB.findById(req.user.book, (err, result) => {
        const promises = result.customers.map((ID) => customerDB.findById(ID));
        Promise.all(promises).then((list) => res.send(list));
    });
});
```

But I would suggest you read about [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate in order to deep populate your customer data